# Are $x,y$ dependent in a bivariate uniform distribution over the unit disk?

Tags: probability, statistics

The professor proposed that I compute the marginals of $x,y$ and then multiply them together. The result that I have for their product is $(4/π^2)*\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}$. Therefore, am I to conclude that $x,y$ are dependent because that product is not equal to $f(x,y) = 1/π$?

Answer (score 1):

In part, yes. 
You must also take account of the values that x and y can take, i.e. each density has an indicator function and the multiplication of both must give you the indicator function of the joint distribution.

In this case

$f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{(1-x^2)}. \mathbb{1}(x \in-1,1)$

$f(y) = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{(1-y^2)}. \mathbb{1}(y \in-1,1)$

$f(x,y) = \frac{4}{\pi^2} . \mathbb{1} (x^2 + y^2 \leq 1)$

So as you can see, not only what you did must match, but also the posible values of x and y.

Furthermore it is easy to see that both variables are dependent because if you know that $y=0$, then $X \sim U(-1,1)$ and if you know that $y=1$ then $P(X=0) = 1$